# Why is OmniAuth::Strategies::Apple giving me nonce_mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, sign-in-with-apple

I am using [omniauth-apple](https://github.com/nhosoya/omniauth-apple) and the Apple button from AppleId.auth.  Omniauth is returning `Authentication failure! nonce_mismatch`.

Any ideas why I keep getting this `nonce_mismatch`?

```
<div id="appleid-signin" data-color="black" data-border="true" data-type="sign in"></div>
<script>
AppleID.auth.init({
  clientId: "app.example",
  scope: "email name",
  redirectURI: "https://my.ngrok.io/users/auth/apple/callback",
  state: "TEST-HEX",
  usePopup: false,
  response_mode: "id_token",
  nonce: "<%= apple_signin_nonce %>",
});
</script>
```

app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
  def apple_signin_nonce
    session["omniauth.nonce"] ||= SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(16)
    session["omniauth.nonce"]
  end
```

and receiving this error

```
web     | Started POST "/users/auth/apple/callback" for 182.253.75.237 at 2022-06-28 10:42:23 +0800
web     | D, [2022-06-28T10:42:23.135569 #67393] DEBUG -- omniauth: (apple) Callback phase initiated.
web     | E, [2022-06-28T10:42:23.970234 #67393] ERROR -- omniauth: (apple) Authentication failure! nonce_mismatch: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, nonce_mismatch | nonce mismatch
web     | Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
web     |   Parameters: {"state"=>"TEST-HEX", "code"=>"...(removed)...", "id_token"=>"...(removed)..."}
web     | Redirected to https://my.ngrok.io/
```

Any insight would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is failing bc when apple returns with a POST you start a new session and all previous values are gone. [Here](https://github.com/nhosoya/omniauth-apple/pull/106#issuecomment-1559825025) is a fix I applied.